# A special subspace of $\mathrm{Max}(R[x])$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

For a commutative ring $R$
with identity it is well-known that if  $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal
ideal of $R$ then $\mathfrak{m}[x]$ is also a maximal ideal of
$R[x]$. Thus, the set $\mathcal{A}=\{\mathfrak m[x]\mid 
\mathfrak m \in \mathrm{Max}(R)\}$ is a subset of $\mathrm{Max}(R[x])$. When we
consider $\mathrm{Max}(R)$ and $\mathcal{A}$ as two subspaces of $\mathrm{Max}(R)$
and $\mathrm{Max}(R[x])$, respectively, with respect to the Zariski
topology on these spaces, I want to show that $\mathrm{Max}(R)$ is
homeomorphism to $\mathcal{A}$. So I define
$\phi:\mathrm{Max}(R)\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ by
$\varphi(\mathfrak m)=\mathfrak m[x]$. Clearly $\phi$ is bijective.
How can we show that $\phi$ is continuous and open?

(Note that $\mathrm{Max}$ means the set of all maximal ideals of a ring and $\mathfrak m[x]$ is the set of all polynomial in $R [x] $ whose coefficients are in $\frak {m} $.)

Comment: Can you tell me why you think $\mathfrak{m}[x]$ is a maximal ideal in $R[x]$?

Comment: the maximal ideal is $(\mathfrak{m},x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **$\frak {m}$ $[x]$ is never  a maximal ideal of $R[x]$**.
Indeed, denoting by $k$ the field $R/\frak m$, the kernel of the canonical quotient morphism $R[x]\to k[x]$ is $\mathfrak m[x]$ so that $R[x]/\mathfrak m$$ [x]=k[x]$, which is never a field, proving that $\frak m$$ [x]$ is never maximal in $R[x]$.

2) **Anyway $ \operatorname {Specmax} R$ is not homeomorphic to $ \operatorname {Specmax} R[x]$ in general.**
For example if $R=\mathbb C$, the space $ \operatorname {Specmax}\mathbb C=\{0\}$ has only one point, whereas the space $\operatorname {Specmax } \mathbb C[x]=\{\langle x-z\vert z\in \mathbb C\}$ has the power of the continuum.

3) **However there is a map...**
The surjective "evaluation at zero" map $ev_0:R[x]\to R:P(x)\mapsto P(0)$ induces a continuous map  $$ \operatorname {Specmax} R\to \operatorname {Specmax } R[x]:\mathfrak m \to ev_0^{-1}(\mathfrak m)=\mathfrak m +XR[X]$$ Since $ev_0$ is surjective this map is a closed immersion (and thus injective) but it is not a bijection in general, as follows from the counterexample in  2).

Comment: When you say the map is continuous (in the Zariski topology..) it is meant $I \mapsto I+x R[x]$ which is continuous because its restriction to the maximal ideals is $spm(R) \to spm(R[x])$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: the map is continuous because it is the  restriction to the prime  of the map on prime spectra, which is continous because it comes from the ring morphism  $ev_0$. I have edited my answer (displayed formula on line before last) to make this clearer.